# Nexus 5 and navigator.device.capture.captureAudio

Tags: android, audio, cordova, cordova-3

There isn't a default audio recorder on the Nexus 5, so calling navigator.device.capture.captureAudio results in:

```
04-01 14:48:08.562 W/System.err(24130): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.provider.MediaStore.RECORD_SOUND }
04-01 14:48:08.562 W/System.err(24130):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
04-01 14:48:08.562 W/System.err(24130):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
04-01 14:48:08.562 W/System.err(24130):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
04-01 14:48:08.562 W/System.err(24130):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
04-01 14:48:08.562 W/System.err(24130):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.startActivityForResult(CordovaActivity.java:901)
04-01 14:48:08.562 D/CordovaActivity(24130): Paused the application!
04-01 14:48:08.562 D/CordovaWebView(24130): Handle the pause
04-01 14:48:08.562 W/System.err(24130):     at org.apache.cordova.mediacapture.Capture.captureAudio(Capture.java:198)
04-01 14:48:08.562 W/System.err(24130):     at org.apache.cordova.mediacapture.Capture.execute(Capture.java:99)
04-01 14:48:08.562 W/System.err(24130):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:65)
04-01 14:48:08.562 W/System.err(24130):     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.execHelper(PluginManager.java:242)
04-01 14:48:08.562 W/System.err(24130):     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:227)
04-01 14:48:08.562 W/System.err(24130):     at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:53)
04-01 14:48:08.562 W/System.err(24130):     at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
04-01 14:48:08.562 W/System.err(24130):     at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
04-01 14:48:08.562 W/System.err(24130):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-01 14:48:08.562 W/System.err(24130):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
```

What are the options for getting an audio recorder working on cordova/phonegap applications for the Nexus 5?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're down to two options:

1. Capture the error, and prompt user to install a recorder app from app store. This might not be easy though; https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5603 says that cordova does the callback with CaptureError.CAPTURE_NO_MEDIA_FILES so it might not be possible to distinguish this error from user returning from recorder without actually recording anything.
2. Modify cordova framework to provide a fallback Activity that can handle the recording, similar to what is already provided for iOS and WP7/8.

Comment: I'd be happy with the first solution if installing an audio recorder worked. I've installed Easy Voice Recorder and Smart Voice Recorder but still get the above error.

Comment: You can try https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.audio.voicerecorder&hl=en - based on it's sources (https://github.com/MiCode/SoundRecorder/blob/master/src/net/micode/soundrecorder/SoundRecorder.java#L665-L682), it should function as cordova expects.

Comment: almost, the Voice Recorder is invoked but I can find no way of saving the recoding which takes me back to the app.